# Subsetting dataframe when comparing two columns with pandas

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, slice

Let say I have a dataframe called `df`:

```
    name        X         Y
0   John        1         1
1   Cindy       1         0
2   Ella        0         1
3   David       0         0
```

I would like to compare columns `X` and `Y` such that when they are both 1, the corresponding row is added to a new data frame called `df2`.

The desired output of `df2` would be this:

```
    name        X         Y
0   John        1         1
```

Moreover, I would like to do the same when

- X is 1 and Y is 0
- X is 0 and Y is 1
- X is 0 and Y is 0.

Comment: So you want 4 different output dataframes ?

Comment: @joao Yes ,indeed. Four different dataframes covering each of the 4 scenarios explained above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
dfs = [y for x,y in df.groupby(['X','Y'])]

df2 = dfs[0]
df3 = dfs[1]
df4 = dfs[2]
df5 = dfs[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
dfs = list(dict(list(df.groupby(['X','Y']))).values())
```